# nHibernate mapping of two classed with two tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am working on web application. I want to map classes with table. Now i have three tables. I want a xml mapping for these tables and classes, but can not change the table structure.

I have detail like this

```
> Table and Fields
>     1. **User**
>      UserID,
>      FirstName,
>      LastName,
>     2. **Detail**
>      DetailID ,
>      UserID,
>      Address,
>      City
     3. Contact
     ContactID
     UserID
     Mobile
     Home

I have two classes. User and Detail
     public class User
    {
     public RegionalPreference()
            {
                RP_Region = new List<RegionalPreference_Region>();
            }
            public virtual uint UserID { get; set; }
            public virtual string FirstName{ get; set; }
            public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
            public virtual Contact Contacts { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    }

     public class Detail
        {
                public virtual uint DetailID { get; set; }
                public virtual uint UserID { get; set; }
                public virtual string Address{ get; set; }
                public virtual string City { get; set; }
        }

> public class Contact
>         {
>                 public virtual uint UserID { get; set; }
>                 public virtual string Mobile{ get; set; }
>                 public virtual string Home { get; set; }
>         }
```

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate has a very [detailed documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/index.html).

This [tutorial](http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.html) might be helpful for you. Since you already have your classes you can skip to **Define the Mapping**.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, constructor `public RegionalPreference()` in your code is incorrect; name of constructor does not match with class name. Also `RP_Region` is never defined or used.

I will not provide you ready to eat mapping file, I will try to explain you how to create one. Trust me, it is very simple.

Refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/) beginner tutorial.

Mapping your `Detail` table with `Detail` POCO is strait forward. I do not see any catch in it. Refer "XML-Based Configuration" in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_configuration.htm) tutorial.

About mapping `User` and `Contact` tables with your POCOs, you need to use `component` in NHibernate. Refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_mapping_component.htm) tutorial.

I hope this helps you.